# Внутренняя тень для LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, shape, android-selector

Никак не могу понять, как можно сделать внутреннюю тень.
Чтобы было так:
[image: Внутренняя тень]
Пытался сделать так:

[Второй ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197892/add-shadow-to-custom-shape-on-android) но ничего не получается, точнее не то, что нужно.

Будьте так любезны скажите, как это сделать, я никак не могу понять.
Я перерыл многие ссылки, но такой результат я получить не смог.
С виду вроде не сложно, а никак не могу додуматься, что сделать нужно.

Это нужно применить к `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197892/add-shadow-to-custom-shape-on-android) есть таки то, что тебе нужно, там где красный прямоугольник со скошенными углами. Если подробнее, то создаем в drawable ресурс shape.xml и добавляем в него следующее:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient
                android:angle="0"
                android:centerColor="#00000000"
                android:centerX="0.95"
                android:endColor="#77000000"
                android:startColor="#00000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Этот drawable нарисует прямоугольник с градиентом слева на право, где левый цвет - полностью прозрачный черный, "центральный" тоже, а конечный - полупрозрачный черный. Получим плавную тень по правому краю. android:centerX="0.95" говорит, что центральный цвет находится на 95% от ширины прямоугольника, то есть почти у правого края. Тень займет правые 5% от вьюшки. Копируем тег item целиком, вставляем под первым и заменяем angle на 90. Получаем тень по нижнему краю. Повторяем для 180 и 270. Получаем нужную тебе тень. Поиграйся с цветом и положением центра, получишь любую нужную тебе тень.

Чтобы применить его, у linearLayout в xml пропиши android:background = "@drawable/shape".
Если нужен цвет, поверх которого рисуем тень, самым первым item'ом ставим

```
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#FFFF00FF"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
```

Полный вариант:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="0"
                android:centerColor="#00000000"
                android:centerX="0.90"
                android:endColor="#77000000"
                android:startColor="#00000000"
                android:type="linear" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:centerColor="#00000000"
                android:centerX="0.96"
                android:endColor="#77000000"
                android:startColor="#00000000"
                android:type="linear" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="180"
                android:centerColor="#00000000"
                android:centerX="0.90"
                android:endColor="#77000000"
                android:startColor="#00000000"
                android:type="linear" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="-90"
                android:centerColor="#00000000"
                android:centerX="0.96"
                android:endColor="#77000000"
                android:startColor="#00000000"
                android:type="linear" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Добавил полный код.

Comment: Я пытался так делать, но не получалось. Но вроде работает.